# Usage of relative pronouns with the word from

Tags: word-order

It is correct to use "from that" in relative clauses as in the following example sentence I wrote?

> Student who finished a middle school, from that is a school you have
>   to obtain diploma to apply for a high school, either go to technical
>   schools...

Or should it be

> Student who finished a middle school, that is a school you have
>   to obtain diploma from to apply for a high school, either go to technical
>   schools...

Answer (score 1):

### Version 2 is closer to being correct (but needs further improvement)

> **A** student who finished middle school, **which** is a school you have to obtain diploma from to **either** apply for high school **or** go to technical school...

In order to use the preposition "from" you need to keep the object of the preposition next to the preposition itself:

> **A** student who finished a middle school, **from which** you have to obtain diploma to **either** apply for high school **or** go to technical school...

Note that the sentence, as you have it constructed now, is not complete. There is no verb for the subject of student and the subject needs an article (**A** student).